# Firebase crashlytics crash reporting via proxy

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I wanted to ask whether it is possible to send firebase crashlytics crash reports via a proxy. We want to hide the IP-addresses of our clients, so all crashes must be reported via this proxy.